# Rails updating attributes of a User Model from OrdersController

Tags: ruby-on-rails, update-attributes

This my code:

class OrdersController

```
def create
  @order = Order.new(params[:order])
    if @order.purchase
      work = GATEWAY.store(credit_card, options)
      result = work.params['billingid']
      current_user.update_attributes(:billing_id => result)
    end
  end
end
```

`billingid` is returned by running `GATEWAY.store(credit_card, options)`
I am trying to save this returned `billingid` into `:billing_id` column in User Model. Is it not possible to update attribute of User model from a that is not UsersController?

Simply put, is it not possible to update an attribute of model #1 from a controller of model #2?

Thanks

UPDATE:
With the help of the men below, I was able to verify two things:
1. result = work.params ['billingid'] returns string
2. That I am able to save into a different model from any controller

However, even though I have attr_accessible :billing_id I am still unable to save the result into billing_id column of User table. I was successful in saving the result in a store_name column of a Store table, so I don't know what it is about User model that is preventing me from saving.

I ran,

```
@mystore = Store.find(current_user)
@mystore.store_name = result            
@mystore.save
```

and it was successful. But,

```
@thisuser = User.find(current_user)
@thisuser.billing_id = result
@thisuser.save
```

This fails even though attr_accessible is set correctly. What else could prevent from saving certain attributes other than attr_accessible? Thanks everyone!

UPDATE 2: User Model

require 'digest'

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

```
has_one :store
has_many :products
attr_accessor :password
# attr_accessible was commented out completely just to check as well. Neither worked
attr_accessible :name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :username, :billing_id
validates :name,  :presence => true,
                :length   => { :maximum => 50 }

validates :email, :presence => true,
                :format   => { :with => email_regex },
                :uniqueness => { :case_sensitive => false } 
validates :password, :presence     => true,
                   :confirmation => true,
                   :length       => { :within => 6..40 } 

username_regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]{1,15})$/

before_save :encrypt_password

def has_password?(submitted_password)
    encrypted_password == encrypt(submitted_password)
end
private
def encrypt_password
  self.salt = make_salt if new_record?
  self.encrypted_password = encrypt(password)
end

def encrypt(string)
  secure_hash("#{salt}--#{string}")
end

def make_salt
  secure_hash("#{Time.now.utc}--#{password}")
end

def secure_hash(string)
  Digest::SHA2.hexdigest(string)
end
```

end
end

UPDATE FINAL: SOLUTION
using @thisusers.errors, I was able to find out that it was trying to validate the presence of password during this request. Once I commented it out, it saved without an issue. I am unsure why this is happening, but I will take it from here. Thanks everyone esp. dmarkow!

Comment: Controllers are really just a way of organizing the functionality of your application, and you can work with whatever models you want in whatever controllers you want.  The code you have shown above looks fine, assuming that `current_user` is an accessible method that returns an instance of a model with a `billing_id` attribute (presumably `User`) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There should be no issue updating any number of models from a controller.

1. Make sure that `work.params['billingid']` actually contains a value.
2. Your `User` model may have some attributes marked as `attr_accessible` (since you have `current_user`, I assume you have authentication, and this often means needing to protect your model's attributes by default). If this is the case, that means that **only** those attributes can be changed by mass assignment (e.g. using `update_attributes`). Either add `billing_id` to the list of attributes that are `attr_accessible`, or don't use mass assignment. (Instead, you would just do `current_user.billing_id = result` and then `current_user.save`)

**Edit:** The problem wound up being a validation error on the `User` model. Always make sure to check the `user.errors` when `user.save` returns false.

Comment: Hi dmarkow,I was able to verify both of those things. I had attr _accessible :billing_id and even tried without any attr_accessible. I tried saving it on a store_name column of  Store model and it actually saved! But I am trying to save it on billing_id column of User model and it just won't do it. Can you think of any other reasons why it won't save to a certain model other than attr_accessible? Thanks

Comment: Why do you accept an answer if your problem is not solved yet? I think dmarkow is right though... show us your User model code.

Comment: So is the `@thisuser.save` line actually failing (i.e. does it return `false`)?

Comment: Yes, this line is failing and returns false. @mystore.save returns true

Comment: So if it's returning false, the next step would be to look at `@thisuser.errors` and see what's causing it to fail. It's likely one of your validations.

Comment: THanks dmarkow! I didn't think of using @thisuser.errors. There was an issue with password validation for some reason. I am unsure why that occurred but once I commented out validates :password, it saved! Thanks a bunch everyone!